# How do I disable touchpad tap to click on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

Well I tried on "mouse and touchpad" but there isn't any option to disable tap to click:

[image]

Then I tried:

```
synclient MaxTapTime=0
```

That returned:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

So how to disable tap to clip on touchpad?

Using Ubuntu 16.04

After I solved the problem with the answer suggested by @Vitor, as sugested in comments I got from `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ YSTEK USB Mouse                           id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7910-1018-13.00.01 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Truevision HD                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`xinput list-props 13`

```
Device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Product ID (263):    1, 1
    Device Node (264):  "/dev/input/event3"
```

Comment: On my machine (14.04) this command disables tapping:  `synclient TapButton1=0`, although this won't help with the error message from `synclient`.

Comment: @wjandrea the question is different but the solution is the same. I will answer it here for users that are looking for "how to disable tap to click on 16.04". Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean. I don't know how to do what you want. Please explain me.

Comment: Open terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, enter `xinput` there, press Enter key, than copy the result to your question. You know how to do it, since you posted some output already.

Comment: I thought it was like `xinput synclient`...

Comment: Now please add output of `xinput list-props 13` if `eGalaxTouch` is the touchpad. I see you have 2 devices that may be a touchpad.

Comment: "After I solved the problem"

I don't see anything telling us *how* you solved the problem.

I see a comment below, but it's voted down and a user saying that it's not related at all. Was that in fact your solution? It's not very clear.

Comment: I edited the question @TacoBob .

Comment: @Pilot6 I added `xinput list-props 13`

Comment: You probably made a typo and gave output of  `xinput list-props 14`

Comment: To close voters. It is not a duplicate in any way.

Comment: @Pilot6 why not? According to the OP, running `sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse` fixed it and that's what your answer to the duplicate also suggests. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is not a good solution. That means that either psmouse is not started, or some custom module is installed that was not added to initramfs, or something else.

Comment: Hardware question - are you using a laptop? I have a Logitech K400 keyboard, which has a trackpad attached. None of the above has worked for me yet. (still trying to figure it out) 

I don't have any trackpad or mouse settings at all, but everything works as it should. I just can't turn off trackpad tap.

Edit: I found the answer, in case anyone else comes here trying to figure it out. "Simple answer without going to page.
"Hold down the blue function key and the left trackpad key simultaneously.


No software required, OS is irrelevant.""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting `pmouse` solved my problem (as suggested by @Pilot6 ):

On terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Then the touchpad options will appear on "mouse and touchpad"

[image]

Comment: did not work for me.