# Touchpad tap stopped working

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

Touchpad tap stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04
I installed genome 3.2 and then removed it, and convert back to unity.
Two finger scrolling is working.
I don't see touchpad settings in settings.
I've tried this solution:

```
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
```

But it says that synaptics driver is not loaded

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

How to get touchpad taps working again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you installed `libinput`. You have two options:

1. Enable tapping with `libinput`. It can be done by adding

   ```
   Option "Tapping" "true"
   ```

to the touchpad section of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf`.

Tapping in `libinput` is disabled by defualt.

2. Remove `libinput`. That will revert to `xorg-synaptics` user space driver. It can be done by

   ```
   sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
   ```

`libinput` is a new user space driver that will replace `xorg-synaptics` in new distro versions. I do not recommend to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried option 1, enable tapping.
What about system setting not showing touchpad settings, like scrolling options?

Comment: Can I remove xorg-synaptics package safely now?

Comment: There is no need to remove it.

Comment: Which packages do I install for libinput?

Comment: It depends on which version and hwe stack is installed.

Comment: You need to logout in order to apply the changes to the configuration file. (I tried triggering the update using `udevadm` without success)

Comment: with the first option I get an error because "Option" is not a recognised option in "that section". Can you provide the complete content of the file?

Comment: `Option "Tapping" "true"` should be added before `EndSection`. You can also ask a new question with your file. It is not convenient to solve this type of troubles in comments.

Comment: I have edited this file as directed and it seemed to work at first but now it's back to the same behavior. The only other option I have after scouring the internet is to remove libinput. I am reticent to do this because it's not my computer. Does anyone have personal experience removing it? Did it cause any problems?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and after a LOT of searching and trial and error I came up with this solution and I am sure It will work in your case as well. Since you tried installing gnome3 and then later un-installed it,it would have changed some settings particularly libinput. Try to remove it and I am sure your touchpad tap will start working again.
I ran-

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

The last code will completely clean all the configuration files and data associated with libinput. Just reboot your computer after this and hopefully it'll start working again as it did in my case!

Comment: You do not have to remove `libinput`. You can enable tapping there.

Comment: Hi Pilot! Thanks for pointing that out. After a lot of searching i did find that libinput has replaced synaptics in newer distros and desktop environs. I was unsure how to enable it. But removing did in fact work in my case.

Comment: Thanks, accepted Pilot6 answer since it provides another option, which I actually used

Comment: Ref. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322413 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Comment: Well, oddly enough, I believe the following line is what caused my keyboard AND touchpad AND USB mouse to stop working at all (as soon as x is started). I can get in on the command line, but I can't get the wifi to work on the command line...so far, I'm not finding a way forward.

sudo apt purge --auto-remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput

Answer (score 1):

Restarting pmouse solved the problem for me. This will enable mouse options. In the terminal, execute:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Then the touchpad options will appear on "mouse and touchpad"
(original thread that suggested https://askubuntu.com/a/811948/567297)

Then you can enable or disable:

1. tap to click
2. two finger scrolling
3. natural scrolling

Comment: didn't appear :(