# Keys don't repeat anymore, touchpad tap and touchpad two-finger scroll don't work anymore

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, touchpad, input-devices

#### The problem:

Since recently, on my Ubuntu 16.04, the keyboard keys don't repeat anymore and the touchpad tap and touchpad two-finger scroll don't work anymore.

The touchpad:

- Tapping the touchpad, single and double, don't work anymore at all
- Scrolling or zooming on the touchpad using two fingers doesn't work anymore at all
- Moving the pointer with the touchpad still works fine
- Both buttons below the touchpad work fine

Key repeat is all weird:

- It repeats a key once between 5 to 10 times
- It repeats the second key around 3 times
- All following keys that are pressed for longer time don't repeat

---

#### Specs and info:

These screens show that the settings are there and set correctly:

[image: Touchpad settings screen]

[image: Keyboard settings screen]

These are my (relevant) specs:

```
System:    Host: jochem-ideapad-700 Kernel: 4.13.0-26-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Unity 7.4.0
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: LENOVO (portable) product: 80RU v: Lenovo ideapad 700-15ISK
```

This is the output of `xinput`:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ PEAQ WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is the (relevant) output of ``:

```
$ synclient |grep "Tap\|Scroll\|TwoFinger"
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 163
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 74
    HorizScrollDelta        = 74
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
```

---

#### What I have tried:

- I [don't have `libinput` installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838061/touchpad-tap-stopped-working).
- [Switching off `i2c_hid` and setting nopnp in boot parameters](https://askubuntu.com/a/632570/378108) didn't work
- [Setting `TapButton3 = 2`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690138/synaptics-touchpad-tap-to-click-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-15-10gnome/700473) didn't solve it (TapButton1 and TapButton2 are already at the correct value?)

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had symptoms similar to yours regarding keys but not touchpad.

The solution I found was from [Fixing Keyboard repeat problems in Kernel 4.13](https://askubuntu.com/a/995948/783464). Check it out to find a more comprehensive guide and explanations.

Writing `showkeys` in a terminal showed that keycode 213 was being pressed and unpressed about once every second, explaining why keys held were being interrupted.

This is caused by the `PEAQ WMI hotkeys` module, that I see you have running too.

## So to fix the keyboard

I typed in a terminal

```
sudo rmmod peaq_wmi
```

and verified that this fixed my problem temporarily. To keep the setting after the computer is restarted, I typed

```
gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and added the following to the file

```
#spams ^@
blacklist peaq_wmi
```

(Note: I do not know if this module was important to the functioning of my computer in any way. I will personally make a note that if something on my pc doesn't work I can try to re-enable it. I'll also check in a month or two to see if I can re-enable it because an update has fixed the issue.)

## To fix the touchpad

according to the post you can try similarly

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

and if this fixes the problem until next time you restard, you can do

```
gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add these lines

```
/sbin/rmmod psmouse
/sbin/modprobe psmouse
```