# Mouse/touchpad does not work on non ubuntu apps

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 for a while now on my laptop. Suddenly, from today morning my touchpad stopped two finger scroll, left click and right click on non ubuntu apps. Although moving the cursor on the screen works and it can recognise links and buttons (as in when I hover over a link it correctly changes the cursor icon to a hand from an arrow pointer). This does not seem to happen for ubuntu apps like Terminal, Document viewer, Libre Office apps. But I am unable to use Google Chrome, Firefox, and other apps.

I can navigate non ubuntu apps like chrome using the keyboard (and right now I am using my keyboard only).

I thought maybe my touchpad is misbehaving but I tried USB mouse as well and the problem persists.

Comment: Maybe because it's late and I'm tired, but: please clarify.  And have you tried shutting down and then turning it back on?

Comment: Also, check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/999303/keys-dont-repeat-anymore-touchpad-tap-and-touchpad-two-finger-scroll-dont-wor?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply RonJohn. Sorry for the late reply. I tried several things in the morning among those was the link shared by you as well. But nothing did work that time. Apparently after day's work was over I shut down my laptop and after restarting the touchpad is back working. Stupid of me to not think of restarting the system in the morning.